# When an API is doing HTTP Token Authentication using Introspection, what should it return if the Introspection server is down or returns a 500?

Tags: http, authentication, token

When an API is doing HTTP Token Authentication using Introspection, what should it return if the Introspection server is down or returns a 500?

I am writing an API and want to adhere to Http standards. If the API fails to validate the token (due to the custom Introspection server being down or returning a 500) should the API return a 401, 422, or a 500?

Also, if this token introspection endpoint is not an Oauth endpoint should it return the same Http code?

I have done some research and found:

1. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-11.xml#authn-header
   This says: "If the protected resource request included an access token and **failed authentication**, the resource server SHOULD include the error attribute to provide the client with the reason why the access request was declined. The parameter value is described in Section 3.1. In addition, the resource server MAY include the error_description attribute to provide developers a human-readable explanation that is not meant to be displayed to end users."
2. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-11.xml#resource-error-codes

This says: "The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed, or **invalid for other reasons**. The resource SHOULD respond with the HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code."

Now the above make me think that for sure when using Oauth Introspection a 401 is the correct approach in the given case and not a 500. The reason being since the authentication was not a success = failure. Does this sound correct? Also, should this be the same for non-Oauth Introspection?

I reviewed Microsoft's code for their .net core API Introspection package. It shows they return a 401 in this case. The code is at: https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Introspection/OAuthIntrospectionHandler.cs

The relevant part is:

```
// Return a failed authentication result if the introspection
// request failed or if the "active" claim was false.
var payload = await GetIntrospectionPayloadAsync(token);
if (payload == null || !payload.Value<bool>(OAuthIntrospectionConstants.Claims.Active))
{
    Context.Features.Set(new OAuthIntrospectionFeature
    {
        Error = new OAuthIntrospectionError
        {
            Error = OAuthIntrospectionConstants.Errors.InvalidToken,
            ErrorDescription = "The access token is not valid."
        }
    });

    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Authentication failed because the authorization " +
                                    "server rejected the access token.");
}
```

Finally I came accross this:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1

Which says: "If the protected resource request does not include authentication
credentials or **does not contain an access token that enables access
to the protected resource**, the resource server MUST include the HTTP
"WWW-Authenticate" response header field; it MAY include it in
response to other conditions as well."

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't want a 4xx error, because it suggests that it might be solvable by the client or at least a client-side error. This is clearly an outage so your error code should at least start with 5.

If you are accessing a external service, that service is down or malfunctioning and the service is critical (e.g.: there's nothing you can do in terms of a fallback) the most appropriate status code might be `503 Service Unavailable`.

Comment: I do not think this is correct per: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-2.1. It says, "If the protected resource request does not include authentication
   credentials or does not contain an access token that enables access
   to the protected resource, the resource server MUST include the HTTP
   "WWW-Authenticate" response header field; it MAY include it in
   response to other conditions as well." If the token cannot be verified, then the token does not enable access to the resource.

Comment: I think all of those are true as well, but the scenario described in that paragraph is the client not including an access token, in your original question you describe a server literally being down. A `401` suggests that the client can "correct" the mistake by sending correct credentials. You are talking about (partial) outage of your system

Comment: I think your answer is correct in most cases. But in the very specific case of authentication I see it as failure to validate the token. Since there was no error in the API being developed, but a 3rd party server of which we have no control. The API that is being developed has no issues, so would a 500 make sense? I think a 422 would make more sense in this case.

Comment: No, I still think that 503 is still the best possible code. 500 is _good enough_ in the sense that it indicates to the client that the client was not mistaken, but it was a server error. 503 is just a more specialized code for this type of situation. 'The system being down' 3rd party or not, does imho overrule that this was authentication related.

Comment: The 3rd party system is in this case 'part of your api'. From the perspective of the client it's not really relevant whether the system that failed was a system you control, or a 3rd party one.

Comment: 422 specifically suggests that there was something wrong with the request body, which is clearly not the case here.

Comment: Lastly, the oauth specification will always defer to the standard HTTP specification for more general failures (or other features). It also wouldn't specifically document other failures such as 502 or 429 because it already inherits this from the specification it builds on top of.

Comment: A 5xx error is definitely better because the key thing here is that once the introspection server is available again, the same client request will work (assuming it's valid) without the client changing anything. 4xx implies the client did something wrong; 5xx implies the server did something wrong.